# How to hover between buttons to display content using Bootstrap3 and Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

*if you see my code and fiddle, the hovering is already working but i want that when a particular text is hovered, only the button relevant to it should be displayed and the previously shown button should be hidden. how can i do that? and it should also hide if i click anywhere on the screen*

I have 2 buttons named "Water" and "soil" which display 1 button each. "1" for Water and 6 for soil. each of it are displayed when the mouse is hovered over either water or soil . Currently if i hover over "water" , 1 displays and then it remains displayed even if i hover over "soil" and 6 becomes activated. In principle, i want that only one category should be displayed. it should be Water or soil and not both. It should work like this:
When i hover over Water, 1 is activated and if i click anywhere on the screen, it disappears or when i hover over soil then it disappears and 6 is displayed and it should work in any order as any button can be hovered first. i have the hover button and close button which i cannot figure out where to insert but this concept is not working.How can i make this work? Here is the fiddle and the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/6u2g58qm/

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {   
    $('#create_btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#create_tab').tab('show')
    })

    
    $('#login_btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#login_tab').tab('show')
    })

     $('#create_btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#create1_tab').tab('show')
    })
    $(".hover_btn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    })

    
    $(".hover_btn").mouseenter(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab1default").css("opacity","1");
    })
   
     
    $(".hover_btn2").hover(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab2default1").css("opacity","1");
    })
    
    $(".hover_btn2").mouseleave(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab2default1").css("opacity","0");
    })
 $(".hover_btn1").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    })

    
    $(".hover_btn1").mouseenter(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab2default").css("opacity","1");
    })
   
     
    $(".hover_btn22").hover(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab3default1").css("opacity","1");
    })
    
    $(".hover_btn22").mouseleave(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab3default1").css("opacity","0");
    })
$("#closeButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab1default").css("opacity","0");
})
});
```

```css
#customTab a {
            padding: 0;
        }

        .flex {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: baseline;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        @media (max-width: 576px) {
            .container {
                padding: 0;
            }

            .btn {
                padding: 3px 6px;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
            .flex .panel-default{
                margin-right: 4px;
            }
            .flex .panel-default>.panel-heading{
                padding: 0;
            }
            .flex .panel-default>.panel-body .btn:last-child{
                margin-top: 4px;
            }
        }

        .btn-dark {
            background-color: #343a40;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .btn-dark:hover,.btn.focus, .btn:focus {
            color: #fff;
        }
        .btn.focus, .btn:focus,.btn:active,.btn:hover , .active >a .btn{
            color: #fff;
            background: blue;
        }
        .nav-tabs{
            border: none;
        }
        
        .hover_btn{
            background-image: url(air.jfif);
            background-size: cover;
            color: #000;
            height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
        }
        
        .hover_btn:hover{
            background-image: url(air.jfif);
            background-size: cover;
            color: #000;
            height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
            opacity: 0.9;
        }
<html lang="en">
```

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main>

      <div class="container" id="customTab">
        <ul class="nav " style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around; border: none;">
          <li><a href="#tab1default" data-toggle="tab" id="test"><span class="hover_btn">Water</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#tab2default" data-toggle="tab"><span class="hover_btn1">soil</span></a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content hover_btn2">
        <div class="hover_btn2">
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab1default">
            <div class="flex ">
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">1</span></li>
              </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2default">
          <div class="flex">
            <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li><a href="#tab3default1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">6</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
             
          </div>
        </div>
    </main>
  </body>

</html>
```

:

Answer (score -1):

You dont need JQuery to do a hover, its simple if you do it with css.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fade in Overlay</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
  <div>Hover me</div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracia its not what i want to implement and for that i think i need jquery? or could you tell me how can i do that with css as your solution is not what my question was

Comment: Can you explain better what you want? You want to hover and see a text right?

Comment: if you see my code and fiddle, the hovering is already working but i want that when a particular text is hovered, only the text relevant to it should be displayed and the previously shown should be hidden. how can i do that? and it should also hide if i click anywhere on the screen

Answer (score -1):

I've implemented what you need in your code...but while editing your code, I noticed you really need to learn basic concepts in coding, many `<divs>` were unfinished, you added the same classes twice...I think you should really go for the basics rather than diving into it. Anyways, I've added the code to change the opacities to 0 when the focus is lost, and FYI you've included the jQuery library but you're using Javascript...Check the snippet :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#create_btn').on('click', function() {
    $('#create_tab').tab('show')
  })


  $('#login_btn').on('click', function() {
    $('#login_tab').tab('show')
  })

  $('#create_btn').on('click', function() {
    $('#create1_tab').tab('show')
  })
  $(".hover_btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  })


  $(".hover_btn").mouseenter(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab1default").css("opacity", "1");
  })


  $(".hover_btn2").hover(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab2default1").css("opacity", "1");
  })

  $(".hover_btn2").mouseleave(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab2default").css("opacity", "0");
  })
  $(".hover_btn1").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  })


  $(".hover_btn1").mouseenter(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab2default").css("opacity", "1");
  })

  $(".hover_btn2").mouseleave(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab3default1").css("opacity", "0");
  })
    $(".hover_btn").mouseleave(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab1default").css("opacity", "0");
  })
  
  $("#closeButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab1default").css("opacity", "0");
  })
});
```

```css
#customTab a {
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .btn {
    padding: 3px 6px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .flex .panel-default {
    margin-right: 4px;
  }
  .flex .panel-default>.panel-heading {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .flex .panel-default>.panel-body .btn:last-child {
    margin-top: 4px;
  }
}

.btn-dark {
  background-color: #343a40;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-dark:hover,
.btn.focus,
.btn:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

.btn.focus,
.btn:focus,
.btn:active,
.btn:hover,
.active>a .btn {
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
}

.nav-tabs {
  border: none;
}

.hover_btn {
  background-image: url(air.jfif);
  background-size: cover;
  color: #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hover_btn:hover {
  background-image: url(air.jfif);
  background-size: cover;
  color: #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>

    <div class="container" id="customTab">
      <ul class="nav " style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around; border: none;">
        <li><a href="#tab1default" data-toggle="tab" id="test"><span class="hover_btn">Water</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab2default" data-toggle="tab"><span class="hover_btn1">soil</span></a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="hover_btn2">
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab1default">
          <div class="flex ">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">1</span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade hover_btn3" id="tab2default">
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li><a href="#tab3default1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">6</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```